# Native memory with low RAM constraint (1g)

Tags: java, docker, graalvm

I'm running a Java application within a Docker with `1g` of maximum RAM. I've reduced the Java heap to `-Xmx256m`. Despite that, the Java process is using much more and very often goes beyond `1g` making it being killed by the OS. I've read about Java [native memory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) and basically understand what is happening.

But except adding enough swap and accepting the potential performance penalty, is there a way to minimize the required memory (including the native memory) ? I've been mentioned to look at [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) : any feedback ? Does it mean, for example, I would need to compile my application for the different architectures (Intel, ARM, ...) ?

Comment: what exact error you are getting ? is it any framework application like spring boot, play,vertx or standalone java app ? also did you check when exactly its getting killed , during startup or during processing ?

Comment: Plain Java. Killed after a while. docker stats is showing the process is using more and more RAM (way more than the 256m of the heap).

Comment: you must be having native memory leak there. Refer this and add those param mentioned in this blog which will help you tracking exactly where native memory is getting consumed. https://www.baeldung.com/native-memory-tracking-in-jvm

Answer (score 0):

regarding using less RAM at runtime, GraalVM Native Image would definitely give you that. Depends on what your app is doing, you can even go much lower than 256M. But yes you would need to compile for each platform separately. Something like GitHub actions can help there.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit or do you have any pointer showing how much less native memory is being used with GraalVM ? The size of the Java heap is not an issue for me.

Comment: I don't have such measurements at hand, but Native Image will use less memory because unlike running on the JVM you don't need memory for the following:

- JVM itself
- Application data
- Loaded bytecodes
- Reflection metadata
- Code cache
- Profiling data
- JIT compiler data structures.

You only need memory for the application and its data. the application contains a slim VM inside, but it's much smaller than the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

JIT (Just-In-Time) and AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation are two different approaches to compiling and executing code in a programming language.

Here are the differences between them

**Compilation Timing**

**JIT**: In JIT compilation, code is compiled and executed on-the-fly, at runtime. When a program is run, the source code or intermediate code is translated into machine code just before it is executed.

**AOT**: AOT compilation occurs ahead of time, typically before the program is run. The entire code is compiled into machine code or a lower-level representation before execution.

**Execution Speed**

**JIT**: JIT-compiled code can have a slightly slower startup time because of the compilation step, but it may optimize code for the specific runtime environment, potentially improving execution speed during the application's lifecycle.
**AOT**: AOT-compiled code generally has faster startup times because there is no need for on-the-fly compilation. However, it may not adapt to the runtime environment as effectively as JIT-compiled code.

**Resource Utilization**

**JIT**: JIT compilation can consume additional memory and CPU resources during the compilation process. Once the code is compiled, it can be more memory-efficient because it optimizes for the specific execution paths.
**AOT**: AOT-compiled code tends to consume less memory and CPU resources during execution since there is no in-memory compilation process. However, it may not be as resource-efficient as JIT-compiled code in terms of execution speed.

**Portability**

**JIT**: JIT-compiled code can be more portable since it can adapt to different runtime environments. It is often used in cross-platform applications.

**AOT**: AOT-compiled code may be less portable because it is optimized for a specific platform or architecture, and recompilation may be required for different environments.

[image]

In Java, only JIT Compilation  running on jvm was previously available. GraalVM enables AOT Compilation (native compilation)

It would be better to choose a more appropriate strategy based on the characteristics required by the system. In this situation, saving memory is important, so I think the AOT compilation will be very helpful

U can Check this Blog. In this blog, when compiled using gralvm, it saves about 40% of memory.

[image]

https://medium.com/graalvm/graalvm-for-jdk-21-is-here-ee01177dd12d

I think u r using Spring Boot, Checking this document will be helpful.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html